# Prolog - sum of divisors - compilation error

Tags: prolog, sum, division

I am trying to create a Prolog program divisor_sum that sums up all the divisors of a number X (excluding X).

```
acc_divisor_sum(X,_,X).
acc_divisor_sum(X,Y,C):- A=:=0, A is X mod N, C is N+1, Y is Y+C, acc_divisor_sum(X,Y,C).
acc_divisor_sum(X,Y,C):- A=\=0, A is X mod N, C is N+1, acc_divisor_sum(X,Y,C).
divisor_sum(X,Y):- acc_divisor_sum(X,Y,1).
```

The error I am getting.

```
   ?- divisor_sum(12,Y).
ERROR: =:=/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
^  Exception: (9) _L144=:=0 ? creep
   Exception: (8) acc_divisor_sum(12, _G204, 1) ? creep
```

What is wrong with my code? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no bound A yet. You need to move the `=:=`-test *after* the `A is ...`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should work with a predicat with 4 args :

```
% @arg1 : Number to study
% @arg2 : current divisor
% @arg3 : current sum of divisors
% @arg4 : final sum of divisors
acc_divisor_sum(X, Div, S, TT)
```

Now, when **0 is X mod N** succeeds, you know another divisor, and you can gain time in the search.